# How to access the value of a variable in a python script when executed from another python script using system() command?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `python script`(**parent_script.py**) which executes another `python script`(**child_script.py**) using `system()` command. In this python script there is a variable(`var1`) whose value I want to return to or access in the parent_script.py script. My current **parent_script.py** is:

```
def call_script():

    cmd = "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 child_script.py --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2"
    output_code = system(cmd)

    if output_code != 0:
        print(strerror(output_code) + ' \n')
        sys.exit(1)
    # Get the value of var1 in child_script.py


if __name__ == '__main__':

    call_script()
```

My current **child_script.py** is:

```
def func1():
    # bunch of other code

    var1 = '2015' # this is the value that I want to access in parent_script.py


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Child Script')
    parser.add_argument('--arg1', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--arg2', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    func1(args)
```

How can I get the value of `var1` returned to or accessed in parent_script.py?

**Note:** I know using subprocess I can execute the python script and get the value of var1 but in this case I am restricted to use system() only to execute the python script. Also the value of var1 in child_script is shown as a dummy value. Actual value is generated by the code that is above it and I haven't shown as it is not relevant.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. With a process, you return the value of `var1` from `func1`. Between processes, you communicate via sockets or streams. There is no notion of accessing the values of a particular variable in another program.

Comment: Use some sort of Inter-Process Communication, like a pipe (anonymous or named), a socket, shared memory, message queue, etc.  At a push you could even write it to a file.  Another alternative is to revisit your design and not run a script as a child process but as a module in the same process.

Comment: @chepner: Except for the fact that they are both Python scripts.  My answer below shows that you *can* in fact do it.

Comment: @zondo can you illustrate through an example? I have also updated my post above to show that I am passing some named arguments to my child_script

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `python2.7`, use `execfile()` instead of `os.system()`:

```
sys.argv[1:] = ["--arg1", "arg1", "--arg2", "arg2"]
try:
    execfile("child_script.py")
except SystemExit as error:
    output_code = error.code
else:
    output_code = 0
```

Then you can use `var1` normally. (This assumes that `global var1` was put at the beginning of `func1()`.)

Note, though, that `execfile()` does not exist in Python3.

Comment: The issue is that I have to pass some named arguments to my child script. How do I do that with this? I have updated my post above to show what is the exact cmd i am executing

Comment: then I can reference `var1` in my parent_script.py?

Comment: Only if you can reference `var1` in `child_script.py`  How you child script is currently written, `var1` isn't a global variable, but I'm hoping that your real script has `global var1` at the beginning of the definition of `func1()`.

Comment: I can make var1 global in child_script. SO with this if I do `print var1` in my parent_script i will get the value of var1 from child script right?

Comment: If you make it global in `child_script.py`, it will be available in `parent_script.py`.  Just try it and see.

Comment: I am getting an error in passing arguments. One of my arguments is `--tags '{"name":"test", "owner":"user1"}'`. I am doing `["--tags","\'{\"name\":\"test\", \"owner\":\"user1\"}\'"]` but getting `error: argument --tags: invalid loads value: '\'{"name":"test", "owner":"user1"}\''`

Comment: You don't need the double quotation marks.  Just pass it as `["--tags", '{"name":"test", "owner":"user1"}]`